# Android intent redirecting to market details page

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent, android-market-filtering

I am using the code below to see if an app exists. If it exists, this will open the app; if not, it will redirect to the market:

```
href="intent://xxx/#Intent;scheme=yyy;package=com.some.app;end"
```

This code redirects to the search result list, but I would like to redirect to the detail page. e.g.`'market://details?id=com.some.app.'`

Comment: Set that as the url then?